# Shell script AT Commands : not able to send sms through serial port

Tags: shell, expect, at-command

I have the below shell script (expect) where I am trying to send SMS. I have referred many stack overflow references and found out that ctrl-z maps to \x1a. However, even after appending it to the message and sending to the port or sending ctrl z separately to the port didn't help me. It timeouts later.

The script is written to send sms in pdu format. Irrespective of that, I believe, this is a generic issue to send ctrl-z to port. If you feel the script has some other errors, please share the solution for the same.

Also the length (34) mentioned below is the length of the (PDU_LENGTH -2)/2 as per the specification. This length doesn't include ctrl-z character.

at_command = "AT+CMGS=34\r"
message_content = "0011000C810056890......"

**Script:**

```
set PROMPT "0"
set timeout "$COMMAND_TIMEOUT"
send "$at_command"
expect {
    "OK" { puts "Command Accepted\n"; }
    "ERROR" { puts "Command Failed\n"; }
    timeout { puts "Unable to connect to $HOSTIP at $HOSTPORT"; exit 1 }
    "*>*" { set PROMPT "1"; }
}

if { "$PROMPT" == "1" } {
    send "$message_content"
    send "\x1a"
    expect {
        "OK" { puts "\nCommand accepted"; }
        "ERROR" { puts "\nCommand failed"; }
        "*>*" { puts "CTRL-Z dint reach UT. Error..."; }
        "*" { puts "Unexpected return value received"; }
    }
}
```

Am very sure the script sends $message_content" to port but exits immediately after sending "$message_content".

**OUTPUT:**

```
AT+CMGS=34

>
```

Comment: Is `message_content` having `\r` at the end ? Don't you get any response, after sending the message ?

Comment: @Dinesh: it dint work either.

Comment: After sending message content, `expect` for something. (which may of some response). Then send try sending the `ctrl+z`. Remove the `expect *`. I suspect on that.  Why you need that first ?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in `c#` with an SMS-Gateway-Modul.

I had to `switch to PDU-Mode first!`
After that i had to transmit the expected PDU-Length and finally the PDU itself.

Every command has to be committed with can carriage return `ASC[13]` and the PDU had to be committed with an `ASC[26]` finally.

Here you can see a schematic(!) flow, how i did it in `c#`:

1) Create PDU and get length

```
int len;
var pdu = PDUGenerator.GetPdu(destination, message, "", out len);
```

2) Switch to PDUMode

```
 SendToCom("AT+CMGF=0" + System.Convert.ToChar(13));
```

3) Announce message length

```
SendToCom("AT+CMGS=" + len + System.Convert.ToChar(13));
```

4) Send PDU and commit

```
SendToCom(pdu + System.Convert.ToChar(26));
```